# How to make ubuntu show on boot menu options

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair, grub-efi

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 in my pc which came pre-installed with windows 10.
I am now in "try ubuntu without install" and the detail of my partitions is as below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB   273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, hidden, esp
 2      274MB   290MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   506GB   506GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      506GB   685GB   178GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      685GB   899GB   215GB   ext4
 5      999GB   1000GB  1049MB  ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag


Model: SanDisk Cruzer Blade (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 7799MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  7799MB  7798MB  fat32        Microsoft Basic Data  msftdata
```

How shold i proceed from here, currently i can only see ubuntu when i have my flash drive connected. I can smoothly log in to windows in the 'windows bootmgr' option in the boot menu. i have already installed ubuntu. My ubuntu is installed in partition number 6. 215GGB.

Comment: @LiveWireBT can you answer this please?

Comment: when you installed Ubuntu 18.04, did you get a msg something like "Ubuntu is successfully Installed, restart the Computer"

Comment: @Pratap yes i got that message

Comment: @mykey did you try above links? Have you tried boot-repair from live session?

Comment: @Pratap because am new in Linux its difficult for me to follow some of those suggestions, i want first to understand the logic probably with a step by step procedure using my diskpart list above

Comment: logon with livesession & with active internet connection. and then run following commands.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`
`boot-repair` when you press enter, it will take you to Graphical tool where you can have general options to repair your boot. probably it should solve the problem.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Pratap i have done this with success; how do i make bios boot on sda1/EFI//ubuntu/shimx64.efi file, thats the instruction on repair summary info

Comment: When you restart the system now what's happening? can you explain.

Comment: Its booting straight to windows, i unplugged the ubuntu usb stick

Comment: 1. Can you check fast boot in windows10 is on or off? We require it to be off. 2. in BIOS settings secure boot should be off.

Comment: Yes, secure boot is disabled, quick boot is off too; also in my boot list from the bios, ubuntu is not listed

Comment: OK, can you access bios options. Is it laptop or desktop? this time go to bios options and then see boot options. Also check if there is legacy/csm in boot mode.

Comment: I am in bios settings , this is a Thinkpad T580. Csm support is off

Comment: Can you on csm and see. Also see boot mode. If it's in UEFI change to BIOS and see.

Comment: Boots straight to windows; i believe my problem is addressed in my previous comment ; about shimx64.efi file, how to make bios boot from it

Comment: Yes. But if Ubuntu is installed successfully.. You should see GRUB, where you can select windows 10 and Ubuntu. As a second try Boot-Repair might have solved this. Means something wrong. I suggest you to try formatting sda6 and 1. reinstall Ubuntu on the same partition sda6. 2. select "device for boot loader" as "sda".  make sure you are in the UEFI boot mode. I am sorry I don't think shimx64.efi is possible.